# Вывод изображений по ссылке из бд

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

В базе данных имею объект

```
{
    "_id": "60f061ab0e766822042088ad",
    "url": "C:\\Users\\Артем\\WebstormProjects\\tz\\img\\42a98d03-5ed7-4b3b-af89-7c4876cb14c3.jpg",
    "size": {
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "createdAt": "2021-07-15T16:26:19.891Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-15T16:26:19.891Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

из него вытаскиваю ссылку и вставляю в img

```
const check = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {


    let list = await Animals.find()

      let arr:any[] = []

    list.forEach(data => {
       
            arr.push(data.url)
        
    })

      const response = arr.map(item => `<img src="${item}" />`).join('\n')

      res.send(response)
  }
  catch (err:any) {
      console.log(err)
  }
};
```

Но вместо изображений получаю только [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkKWc.png) подскажите как можно решить данную проблему

Comment: А вы уверены что весь мир имеет доступ к вашему диску `C:`?

Answer (score 0):

Решил через статику

```
app.use('/static', express.static('img'))
  const response = arr.map(item => `<img src="http://localhost:5000/static/${item}" />`).join('\n')
```